# How to specify an organization with the name of city

Tags: names

There is an organization, Federation of Literary and Art Circles, in my hometown city and I need to name it. So basically it is a combination problem of organization and city name. The following two choices are in my head for now:

> 1. (Alto) City Federation of Literary and Art Circles
> 2. Federation of Literary and Art Circles of (Alto) city.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Why do you place the town name in parentheses? Do you actually need the word "city" at all? Why not *Alto Federation of Literary and Art Circles*?

Comment: I might use  Federation of Literary and Art Circles (Alto) but it depends on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, the most important word comes first or last, as in *United States of America* or *European Union*.  However, with a name as long as the *Alto Federation of Literary and Art Circles*, most people will use a nickname or an acronym. AFLAC is already taken, as you probably know. ACFLAC is (relatively) unencumbered.

That said, parentheses don’t work naturally with acronyms or web searches. It’s a matter of taste, perhaps, but for a formal name I’d lean towards **The Alto City Federation of Literary and Art Circles.**